# How to work with Oauth2 in phalcon?

Tags: php, rest, phalcon, oauth-2.0

I am looking for some simple creation of Token to authenticate for each Rest Api call.

Actually I am new to this authentication process, I gone through some websites and forums but I didn't get proper idea on where to store the token after login and how to use it for authentication.

Please provide me with an example code?

**Note:** I was creating Rest Api for my website only, so no need of other keys are required to create access token I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Some oAuth2 examples for using with Phalcon:

https://github.com/sergeyklay/awesome-phalcon#authentication--oauth

RESTful examples:

https://github.com/sergeyklay/awesome-phalcon#restful

Comment: I gone through these websites..But i was little confused with how to use my token which i created randomly for authentication of APIS